# Paint a TPanel to an Image and save it in dataset

Tags: xml, image, delphi, save, panel

I have a panel (TPanel) who is a parent for other many panels created on runtime. I want to save all this like an image(bitmap, graphic, no matter..) to a datast. I used this:

```
image1.Picture:= nil;
panel1.PaintTo(image1.Canvas.Handle,0,0);
table1.edit;
table1.FieldByName('Im').Assign(image1.Picture.Bitmap);    
table1.Post;
```

and this:

```
var
Bitmap: TBitmap;
BmpField: TGraphicField;
begin
BmpField := table1.FieldByName('Im') as TGraphicField;
Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
try
Bitmap.Width := Panel1.Width;
Bitmap.Height := Panel1.Height;
Panel1.PaintTo(Bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0);
table1.Edit;
BmpField.Assign(Bitmap);
table1.Post;
finally
Bitmap.Free;
end;
end;
```

thanks to [Ken White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62576/ken-white) and both methods work but... When I save the dataset as .xml and I open that .xml in an text editor, the image saved there is an infinite string (not large, but infinite!).
 Is there any way to save this panel (with the panels inside) like a normal image in the database and the saved .xml string to be a decent one? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explained this in the other post. The image has to be encoded (converted to something other than binary) to be written to the XML. It isn't "infinite". It's the encoded image. You cannot store a binary image as an actual image in the XML. That *is* a decent one. :-)

Can you explain what your actual goal is here? The image is perfectly fine in the XML's graphic field. (You can write it there and then retrieve it and display in a `TImage`, right?) I don't understand why you keep wanting to *read* a binary database field as a *string*; it's *not a string*. It's a binary field containing a graphics image. What would a string picture of a green meadow look like?

Comment: Yes. The image is fine and is readable with an TImage. My only concern is that when i saved that 'xml' file with only 1 image stored inside the file have 2,7kb while the biolife.xml file (in delphi's demo) having much more pictures stored inside have only 1,4kb.<br>Is that normal, or i've done something wrong? My question is that is OK just paint an TComponent to an image , or i have to do something more?

Comment: The images in Biolife are probably lower color depth (bits per pixel) and therefore smaller, because they were created long ago in Windows 3.1 days IIRC. (I think Biolife was originally in a Paradox database when Delphi 1 was released, and then later just converted to a ClientDataSet around Delphi 5 or so.) If you can save and then reload the image, you've done nothing wrong.

Comment: OK. Case close. Thank you very much.